# How to make fixed nav bar stick to picture when page is getting smaller

Tags: html, css

I have created picture-logo and I have fixed it to the top of the page. I have fixed menu bar under it. But when I reduce the size of page picture shrinks, but menu stays in the fixed position creating gap between picture and menu like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIXaJ.png . When page is normal size, picture and nav bar are in the right position like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN3AP.png . How to make nav stick to image? The idea is when scrolling the page image and nav stay fixed on the top of the page, but once pages gets smaller image and nav moves together without leaving that space between them. I mean instead nav staying at 190px from top fixed it moves to under picture here https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue49V.png . At the moment image gets smalle, but nav bar stays fixed position. I have tried to look at this online, but I am not able to find a solution.

My code is:

```
<body>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<img src="Capture.JPG" width="1210" height="100" class="header">
<nav>    
    <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav></body>
```

```css
/*header*/
.imageheader{
    position:fixed;
}
.header{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    border-bottom: 0px #BCB3B3 solid;
}
nav{
    position: fixed;
    top:190px;
    background-color: #d3af21;
    margin-left: 0px ;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C6C5C5;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 60px;      
}
.menu a {
    color: black;
    font-size: 27px;
    text-decoration: none;  
}
.menu li {
    padding: 35px;
    background-color: #d3af21;
    height:25px;    
}
.menu {
    display: flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 50.5vw;
    margin: 0px 30vw;
    font-family: "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, "serif"      
}
body{
    height: 2000px;
}
```